# What part of speech is 'many' in "as many A's as B's"?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

At first glance, it seems like the "many" in "There are as many A's as B's" is an adjective. However, we can't substitute an arbitrary adjective in this sentence. Compare:

"There are as many A's as B's." (correct)

"The A's are as many as the B's." (incorrect)

"There are as numerous A's as B's." (incorrect)

"The A's are as numerous as the B's." (correct)

I'm curious about how to describe the reason why two of these feel 'correct' (to me, as a native speaker) and two of them do not. Is 'many' here a different part of speech than an adjective? Or is "as many as" just its own grammatical construction with its own rules?

Comment: "Many" belongs to the word class (POS) "**determinative**"

Comment: In particular, it is the kind of determiner (or determinative, if you go to a different church) known as a **Quantifier**. That is, it determines quantity, in the case of _many_ the integer quantity associated with count nouns; _much_ is the quantifier that determines the real number quantities associated with mass nouns (though usually they're counted in integer units like tonnes).

Answer (score 1):

"Many" here is a **determiner.** Other degree determiners also work in this kind of construction:

1. I have as **few** coins as you do.
2. I have as **much** money as you do.
3. I have as **little** money as you do.

Comment: Better still is 'determin**ative**', with determin**er** reserved for its function. Note the different spellings.

Comment: @BillJ In Huddleston & Pullum's terminology, yes.

Comment: What do you call its function, then?

Comment: @BillJ The usual answer is to use the word "determiner" for both the syntactic category and the lexical one. H&P's terminology avoids this ambiguity, at the cost of being more complex.

Comment: The syntactic category is the lexical one. I'm talking about word class vs function. IN the case of those items in your examples, their word class is determinative and their function is that of determiner. Unless, of course, one subscribes to Quirk et al,, in which case it's the other way round, where determinative is the function and determiner the word class.